# TimeSeries - Values & Dates

Tags: time-series, display

How can I display a TimeSeries object in a Table or Grid so that I could see the Dates and corresponding Values next to each other? I wrote the following code:

`dates = Table[0, {i,Length[WeatherData["CYYZ","TotalPrecipitation",{{1985,1,1,0,0,0}{1986,1,1,0,0,0},"Day"}]["Dates"]]}];
Do[dates[[t]]=DateList[WeatherData["CYYZ","TotalPrecipitation",{{1985,1,1,0,0,0},{1986,1,1,0,0,0},"Day"}]["Dates"][[t]]],{t,1,Length[dates]}];
Transpose[{dates,WeatherData["CYYZ","TotalPrecipitation",{{1985,1,1,0,0,0},{1986,1,1,0,0,0},"Day"}]["Values"]}] // Grid`

but it's, unfortunately, relatively time-demanding even when there are only approx. 365 values as in the example above. The main problem is that `TableView`apparently does not accept the dates when they are in `DateObject` form.

Answer (score 5):

```
wd = WeatherData["CYYZ", "TotalPrecipitation", 
                {{1985, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1986, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Day"}];

Grid[wd, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Note: In version 10, you can use

```
Grid[{DateList[#][[;;3]], #2}& @@@ Normal @ wd, Dividers -> All]
```

If you have to use `TableView`, you can change the first column of `wd` to `DateString` or to `String`:

```
wda = MapAt[DateString, wd, {All, 1}];
wdb = MapAt[ToString, wd, {All, 1}];
Row[TableView /@ {wda, wdb}]
```

[image]

or to a `DateString` with date format of your choice, e.g.,

```
wdc = MapAt[DateString[#, {"{", "Year", ",", "Month", ",", "Day", "}"}] &, wd, {All, 1}];
TableView[wdc]
```

[image]

Comment: The first code does not seem to work for me, I tried ctrl+c and ctrl+v and only got `Grid[TimeSeries[...],Dividers->All]`.

Comment: @Skumin, for version 10, you can use `Grid[{DateList[#][[;;3]],#2}&@@@Normal@wd, Dividers -> All]` instead.

Comment: This works fine, thank you!

Comment: @Skumin, glad it was useful.